# Disallow all parameters in a specific url in robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I would like to disallow all parameters in a specific url.

If i add this rule :

```
Disallow: /*?*
```

It works but for all url

What i would like to do :

```
Disallow: /my-specific-url/*?*
```

But according to Google Webmaster Tools, this rule doesn’t work.

Comment: Did you include the `User-agent: *` line when you tested it on GWT? The User-agent line is required.

Comment: @plasticinsectyes, i have `User-agent: *` I should have posted the complete file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example looks like it should be working, but you do need to include the User-agent line. The following robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /my-specific-url/*?*
```

Will block the following URLs:

```
http://example.com/my-specific-url/?
http://example.com/my-specific-url/?a=b
```

but it will not block the following:

```
http://example.com/my-specific-url/
http://example.com/some-other-url/?a=b
```

Note that the trailing * is harmless but serves no useful purpose. A cleaner way to do exactly the same thing would be:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /my-specific-url/*?
```

Also note that wildcards are supported by the major search engines, but they are not supported by many other crawlers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does’t work. I’ve added the 2 lines at the beginning of the robots.txt. I’ve tested this url : `my-specific-url?amp%2525253Bamp%2525253B=&p=4` with google Webmaster site map test tools and it says the URL is authorized. I know the URL is weird. I have a bug with a ecommerce CMS (Prestashop) and i can’t find where do these url come from. So i want to ask Search engine not to explore this url because i have a lot of duplicate content. Of course, i’l trying to find where the bug comes from.

Comment: It works now. Sorry, I have made a simple mistake : i forgot to remove the slash. So this solution is working : `Disallow: /my-specific-url*?*` Also, @FarhadD solution is working : `Disallow: /my-specific-url*=*` Can you update your answer ?

Answer (score 2):

While you can't use regular expressions, you are allowed to use wildcards

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#url-matching-based-on-path-values

Have you tried something like

```
Disallow: /my-specific-url/*var1=*
```

Comment: This will block URLs with the given path that have a specific named parameter. (var1 in this case) OP is asking how to block URLs with the given path that have **any** parameters.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if just using Disallow: /my-specific-url/*=* will work - you could try it and use the Robots.txt tester in Webmaster Tools to see if that functions as you expect it to. If not, your best option is to list all your parameters one by one in the robots.txt.

Comment: Yes, i can’t list all the parameters because actually i have a bug with a ecommerce CMS (Prestashop). It generates randomly a lot of URL with weird parameters like `my-specific-url?amp%2525253Bamp%2525253B=&p=4`. It causes a lot of duplicate content on the category pages. I can’t find for the moment where do these url come from. So i want to ask Search engine not to explore this urls. Of course, i’m trying to find where the bug comes from.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Disallow: /my-specific-url/*=*` doesn’t work. I’ve tested with GWT sitemap tester.

Comment: It works now. Sorry, I have made a simple mistake : i forgot to remove the slash. So this solution is working : `Disallow: /my-specific-url*=*` Also, @plasticinsect solution is working : `Disallow: /my-specific-url*?*`